# Why was 'Lee Evans: So what now?' cancelled?

Tags: so-what-now

I watched [So What Now](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280269/) a few years ago. I think it's probably one of the most underrated sitcoms I've seen and that it was well made and funny but it only ran for one series.

Why was this cancelled? Was this Lee Evans decision or the BBC's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around I found this [interview](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/moslive/article-2299933/Lee-Evans-I-bullied-I-went-kids-teachers--I-easy-target.html) with Lee where he says.

> ‘I was writing the scripts and then I’d get on set and I’d be given a script with someone else’s name on it. It was like being punched in the stomach and you’d have to start performing feeling like that. 
>   ‘The show turned into something completely different from what I intended it to be. It was as if they didn’t trust me, as if they didn’t think I was good enough a writer, but it didn’t work. I had to walk away from doing any more series. I just went home.’

So it was Lee himself.